# PHP Associative Array

Tags: php

PHP

```
<?php
$truck['Toyota']=Tundra;
$truck['Nissan']=Titan;
$truck['Dodge']=Ram;

print "<br />Toyota makes the".$truck['Toyota']."<br />";
print "Nissan makes the".$truck['Nissan']."<br />";
print "Dodge makes the".$truck['Dodge']."<br />";
?>
```

I am learning PHP by tutorial:
An Associative Array is an array in which the keys are associated with values.

And, when viewed in a browser...

```
Toyota makes the Tundra
Nissan makes the Titan
Dodge makes the Ram
```

NOT SO!
I get:

```
Toyota makes theR
Nissan makes theR
Dodge makes theR
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Never look at browser screen. What is *HTML source* you've got?

Answer (score 5):

OK so everyone has pointed out that you need to quote your strings, but that's not the real problem.

(The reason that your code is not throwing an error right now is because the strings you forgot to quote are treated as PHP "bare strings" -- basically an undefined constant whose name is used as the value, you should not use/rely on this.)

Now for the real problem: it looks like you have already defined $truck to be a string further up in your code, so when you try to read/write to it as if it were an associative array, you are really read/writing the first character in that originally defined string (the string key your are using is converted to an int). Since the last assignment is $truck['Dodge'] = "Ram", the first character in $truck is changed to an "R", and that's what you are then seeing in your output.

You should (and this case need to) define $truck as an array before you start using it like one:

```
$truck = array();

$truck['Toyota'] = "Tundra";
$truck['Nissan'] = "Titan";
$truck['Dodge'] = "Ram";
```

Even better, for best practices, you should use a different variable name for the first $truck (string) and the second $truck (array) so it's not confusing:

```
// some code that I imagine comes before your example
$truck = "Ford F150";
// ... 

$trucks = array();

$trucks['Toyota'] = "Tundra";
$trucks['Nissan'] = "Titan";
$trucks['Dodge'] = "Ram";

print "<br />Toyota makes the".$trucks['Toyota']."<br />";
print "Nissan makes the".$trucks['Nissan']."<br />";
print "Dodge makes the".$trucks['Dodge']."<br />";
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for that help - appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around string literals. E.g.:

```
<?php
$truck['Toyota'] = "Tundra";
$truck['Nissan'] = "Titan";
$truck['Dodge'] = "Ram";
```

A good idea is to enable error reporting, so you will be told about these issues by the php interpreter. Stick this line at the top of your script (next after `<?php`):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using constants `Tundra` `Titan` and `Ram` instead of strings. Have you defined those constants elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$truck['Toyota']="Tundra";
$truck['Nissan']="Titan";
$truck['Dodge']="Ram";
```

I think its a syntax error.

Comment: The posted code doesn't contain any syntax errors.  Only logical/bad practice errors.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put your strings inside quotation marks:

```
$truck['Toyota']='Tundra';
$truck['Nissan']='Titan';
$truck['Dodge']='Ram';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the post has been edited by Stack Overflow or it lost them but your values are not wrapped in single quotations..

Also, just a piece of advice; concatenation is only required on single quote strings you can wrap your variables in braces to save that 0.00001 msec :)

Comment: Variable interpolation into strings is compiled as concatenation; there will be *no* runtime performance difference between `"foo $bar baz"` and `"foo " . $bar . " baz"`.  The two expressions are 100% equivalent in terms of behavior and performance.

Comment: I've always assumed that the process of reading out variables wrapped in braces sped up the output (impossibly small improvement but an improvement none the less) Perhaps this has changed if you're saying so?

Comment: @cdhowie - if what you are saying is true, you've answered one of my "I wonder but never really found out" questions

Comment: I've always assumed it made a really small improvement. At least from the posts I've read on forums its always advised to avoid concatenation because interpolation of the variables takes processing power. I'm still baffled at the downvote

Comment: As to the downvote, I can't answer that because I didn't do it. But yes, concatenation and interpolation compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: I did not know that, well at least I do now!

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting and reduce the code to more quickly fix if you've found the error:

```
<?php
# display errors and show all warnings and errors, that's helpful:
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);

$truck['Toyota']=Tundra;
$truck['Nissan']=Titan;
$truck['Dodge']=Ram;

echo "<br />\n";

# when doing the same thing multiple times, take foreach:
foreach ($truck as $manufacturer => $model)
{
    echo $manufacturer, ' makes the ', $model, ".<br />\n";
}
```